# Fetch data from Mysql database through node and then access it in typescript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript

My question is that how can we access data from mysql database through node and then access this data in typescript class. I can get data from mysql database but i cant find a way that how can i get this data from server.js(A file where i have get data through node from mysql) into typescript class.
Please help me it will be very helpful for me.
Thanks

Comment: Does your typescript code run on your server (in node.js) or in a browser? Please [edit] your question to explain your situation with more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Nodejs driver for MySQL [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). You can use this to connect to mysql in nodejs. Typescript is a superset of javascript. Every javascript library will work in typescript. The only difference is that you might need to create a d.ts file by yourself if there isn't an existing one.